# The logical equivalency of P→Q and ¬P ∨ Q?

Tags: logic

I am trying to reduce ¬(P ∧ ¬Q) into a simpler and more manageable form. So far, I have used De Morgan's Theorem to reduce the proposition into ¬P ∨ ¬¬Q, from which I simplified the double negation into ¬P ∨ Q. When I looked at the truth table using [this site](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/https://), it looked as if it had the same truth table as if-then or logical implication. Is there a name for this theorem? Or is it invalid for some reason?

In other words, is P → Q a logical equivalence of ¬(P ∧ ¬Q) and ¬P ∨ Q and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $P \implies Q, \lnot P \vee Q,$ and $\lnot(P \wedge \lnot Q)$ are all equivalent.  The truth table is an adequate proof of this.  The last two are related through DeMorgan's laws.  The equivalence of the implication often is the definition of the implication.  I don't know a name for the transformation of the implication into one of the others.

Comment: It's often called 'Implication' :)

Answer (score 0):

$\neg P \lor Q$ implies that if $\neg P$ is false, then $Q$ must be true since one of them (not P or Q) must be true. If $\neg P$ is false, then $P$ is true, thus $P$ implies $Q$.